# XSD and XML - Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, xsd-validation

Probably this has been asked many times.But I went through all the posts but could not clear my error as I have no knowledge about XML and XSD. Can somebody please find out the error?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTMLQuestion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com ./HTMLQuestion1.xsd" xmlns="urn:Test.Namespace" >
<HTMLContent>
<html>
  abcd
</html>

</HTMLContent>
<FrameHeight>450</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

This is the schema HTMLQuestion1.xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:Test.Namespace" xmlns="urn:Test.Namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="HTMLQuestion">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="HTMLContent">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="html"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="FrameHeight"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The error I get is

```
cvc-elt.1.a : Cannot find the declaration of element 'HTMLQuestion'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem.

I have created the XML schema file as mentioned bu you :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:Test.Namespace" xmlns="urn:Test.Namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="HTMLQuestion">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="HTMLContent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="html"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:short" name="FrameHeight"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now i created xml based on the above XSD, as mentioned here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="urn:Test.Namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Test.Namespace HTMLQuestion1.xsd ">
<HTMLContent>
<html>p:html</html>
</HTMLContent>
<FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

This does not show any error. You can proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have supplied the process with the location of the schema for namespace `http://www.w3schools.com`, but you do not have any elements in this namespace. You need to use the xsl:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute to supply the location of a schema for no-namespace elements.

If you are hoping to learn all you need to know about XSD from the w3schools site, then think again. It can be very handy as a quick reference (like those one-page quick reference cards to remind you of command syntax or keystroke combinations) but it's no way to acquire the concepts. Get yourself a decent book, for example Walmsley or van der Vlist.

Comment: Since I dont have namespace should I have to change xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com ./HTMLQuestion1.xsd" to xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./HTMLQuestion.xsd" ?